# Unpack nested json into a dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

**background**

I am trying to access data from the following [API](https://api.opennem.org.au/station/). This is a huge nested json with nested dicts. I am trying to make more readable. the format of the json file is as per this [link](https://api.opennem.org.au/docs#tag/Stations/operation/stations_station__get) (right hand side, click expand all)

**what I've tried**

I've searched SO and other websites, pd.json_normalize seems to be the answer, but I've tried several ways, and it only ever unpacks one layer.

```
# Attempt 1
url = 'https://api.opennem.org.au/station/'
response = requests.get(url).json()
df2 = pd.json_normalize(response, max_level=0)
print(df2)

# Attempt 2
url = 'https://api.opennem.org.au/station/'
response = requests.get(url).json()
df = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path=['facilities'])
print(df)
```

**current incorrect output**

```
  version  ...                                               data
0  3.11.3  ...  [{'id': 488, 'code': 'ADP', 'name': 'Adelaide ...

[1 rows x 5 columns]
```

**help requested**

Anyone know how I can unpack this large nested json into a dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) with nested lists for normalize `data` and `facilities`:

```
df2 = pd.json_normalize(response, ['data',['facilities']])
```

---

```
print(df2.head(3))

    id  station_id        code dispatch_type  active  capacity_registered  \
0  689         488     ADPBA1L          LOAD    True                 6.27   
1  690         488     ADPBA1G     GENERATOR    True                 6.27   
2  516         372  ALBANY_WF1     GENERATOR    True                21.60   

  network_region  unit_number  unit_capacity  approved network.code  \
0            SA1          1.0           6.27      True          NEM   
1            SA1          1.0           6.27      True          NEM   
2            WEM          NaN            NaN      True          WEM   

  network.country network.label  \
0              au           NEM   
1              au           NEM   
2              au           WEM   

                                     network.regions  network.timezone  \
0  [{'code': 'NSW1'}, {'code': 'QLD1'}, {'code': ...  Australia/Sydney   
1  [{'code': 'NSW1'}, {'code': 'QLD1'}, {'code': ...  Australia/Sydney   
2                                  [{'code': 'WEM'}]   Australia/Perth   

  network.timezone_database  network.offset  network.interval_size  \
0                      AEST             600                      5   
1                      AEST             600                      5   
2                      AWST             480                     30   

   network.interval_shift  network.has_interconnectors  \
0                       5                        False   
1                       5                        False   
2                       0                        False   

   network.intervals_per_hour        fueltech.code         fueltech.label  \
0                        12.0     battery_charging     Battery (Charging)   
1                        12.0  battery_discharging  Battery (Discharging)   
2                         2.0                 wind                   Wind   

  fueltech.renewable status.code status.label           registered  \
0               True   committed    Committed                  NaN   
1               True   committed    Committed                  NaN   
2               True   operating    Operating  2018-10-12T00:00:00   

                        approved_at  emissions_factor_co2 approved_by  
0                               NaN                   NaN         NaN  
1                               NaN                   NaN         NaN  
2  2020-12-09T15:34:49.465445+00:00                   NaN         NaN
```

Bonus:

If need also scalars in `network.regions`:

```
df2 = pd.json_normalize(response, ['data',['facilities']])
df2['network.regions'] = [[y['code'] for y in x] for x in df2['network.regions']]
df2 = df2.explode('network.regions').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: @BobbyHeyer - You are welcome. Added bonus for `network.regions` if necessary ;)